# skywalking-backend-js TypeError

Tags: javascript

###### this is error info, Look at the buffer error in the code, but I don't know where the source is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ECFR.png)

```
    TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
        at Function.from (buffer.js:331:9)
        at ContextCarrier._this.decode (/app/v7-mopower/node_modules/skywalking-backend-js/src/trace/context/ContextCarrier.ts:43:19)
        at ContextCarrier.set (/app/v7-mopower/node_modules/skywalking-backend-js/src/trace/context/ContextCarrier.ts:61:32)
        at /app/v7-mopower/node_modules/skywalking-backend-js/src/trace/context/ContextCarrier.ts:88:95
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Function.ContextCarrier.from (/app/v7-mopower/node_modules/skywalking-backend-js/src/trace/context/ContextCarrier.ts:88:66) 
        at Server._sw_request (/app/v7-mopower/node_modules/skywalking-backend-js/src/plugins/HttpPlugin.ts:151:40)
        at Server.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at Server.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/@pm2/io/src/metrics/httpMetrics.ts:181:25)
        at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:790:12)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
```

###### this is startd code

```
import agent from 'skywalking-backend-js';

export class M7Skywalking {
  static tryLoad(serviceName: string) {
    if (!process.env.SW_AGENT_NAME || !serviceName) {
      return;
    }
    agent.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: There was no problem before, but in the last half a month, as long as the Java service accesses nodejs, the process will exit

Comment: Therefore, the current solution is to disable the plug-in to ensure that the service is available

Comment: Based on the error it looks like you're trying to pass something else then a string to a function that expects a string or a buffer. It could be the service name. Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: Not yet, because this problem cannot be reproduced using the same code, but in the website, as long as the Java service accesses the node service, the process exits

Have the same problem
https://github.com/apache/skywalking/issues/7505